If Father’s profession stated on marriage does that mean he is not dead
Marriage certificate gives groom’s father’s name and profession. It doesn’t state deceased. Therefore, Could I assume groom’s father is still alive the date of marriage?
Certificate was issued in Wales in 1917.

In your original post you didn't say where the certificate was issued. It really matters because the answer can vary. For example, in Scotland, on a marriage certificate they were pretty meticulous in recording whether a parent was alive or dead. On the other hand in Ireland there was no common practice. Sometimes you see deceased but in many cases it doesn’t say. Just because the occupation was given did not mean he was alive. Suspect it may be the same in other jurisdictions.

Agreed. In England and Wales, a common scenario is a blank father's name meaning illegitimacy. But then I found a legitimate groom who had declined to give his father's name. This appeared to be done in solidarity with his bride who was illegitimate and whose father's name was omitted. In trying to understand this, I discovered that there were few rules about the content of that item.

I suspect that most jurisdictions were like how Adrian describes Ireland: it all depended on the registrar. If he was a meticulous sort who interrogated the parties thoroughly (or knew -- and remembered! -- everyone's genealogy) and carefully wrote it all down, then absence of "the late" is meaningful. If it was a busy registry office and they caught the assistant on a bad day, then even the presence of "the late" may be meaningless.

Specific to the question "does the presence of an occupation indicate that he's still alive to pursue said occupation": no, it doesn't. A person's profession could become as much a part of his identity as his name, and whether the clerk bothered with "formerly" or similar verbiage was not indicative of anything much.

Sorry, I mean "how Elwyn describes Ireland". Just missed the dratted edit window.
